# how do I extract characters consecutive to the substring and the substring itself After checking if string array contains the required substring

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

Im trying to deal with the following string array called "wifis":-

```
[SSID: Stephen Joseph, BSSID: ##:a6:##:c0:21:##, capabilities: [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS], level: -78, frequency: 2442, timestamp: 998653673499, hs2Info: <none>, distance: ?(cm), distanceSd: ?(cm), SSID: TP-LINK_G6D356, BSSID: 30:b5:c2:f5:$$:56, capabilities: [WPA-PSK-CCMP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS], level: -86, frequency: 2452, timestamp: !!!653673417, hs2Info: <none>, distance: ?(cm), distanceSd: ?(cm), SSID: cbtap998852211C:CF:7F:0A:AC:33, BSSID: 5e:cf:7f:0a:ac:91, capabilities: [ESS], level: -46, frequency: 2412, timestamp: 238653673402, hs2Info: <none>, distance: ?(cm), distanceSd: ?(cm), SSID: Tech_D0008214, BSSID: 70:5a:9e:65:30:56, capabilities: [WPA-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][ESS], level: -88, frequency: 2462, timestamp: 238653673422, hs2Info: <none>, distance: ?(cm), distanceSd: ?(cm), SSID: Tech_D0018138, BSSID: 50:09:59:83:ee:05, capabilities: [WPA-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][ESS], level: -91, frequency: 2437, timestamp: 238653673427, hs2Info: <none>, distance: ?(cm), distanceSd: ?(cm)]
```

and I wish to check and extract `cbtap998852211C:CF:7F:0A:AC:33` and separate out `cbtap`as another string, `99885221` as another bcz its a dynamic 8 digit and the rest `1C:CF:7F:0A:AC:33` as another string.

and its BSSID number `5e:cf:7f:0a:ac:91` from above String array.
So as to check I have done `if(Arrays.asList(wifis).contains(confirmation)){` where confirmation is `cbtap` But how do I extract it and do the the above mentioned tasks.Please suggest the apprach.

Comment: What for things can be expected about the String? Is the `99885221` part always the same amount if digits? Does the `, BSSID: ` part always come directly after the SSID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you break a String, you must use a key to find the first part. I assumed that tbtap is the key.

Note that the ip has 6 parts, not 5 as you wrote.

```
     String s = "[SSID: Stephen Joseph, BSSID: ##:a6:##:c0:21:##, capabilities: [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS], level: -78, frequency: 2442, timestamp: 998653673499, hs2Info: <none>, distance: ?(cm), distanceSd: ?(cm), SSID: TP-LINK_G6D356, BSSID: 30:b5:c2:f5:$$:56, capabilities: [WPA-PSK-CCMP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS], level: -86, frequency: 2452, timestamp: !!!653673417, hs2Info: <none>, distance: ?(cm), distanceSd: ?(cm), SSID: cbtap998852211C:CF:7F:0A:AC:33, BSSID: 5e:cf:7f:0a:ac:91, capabilities: [ESS], level: -46, frequency: 2412, timestamp: 238653673402, hs2Info: <none>, distance: ?(cm), distanceSd: ?(cm), SSID: Tech_D0008214, BSSID: 70:5a:9e:65:30:56, capabilities: [WPA-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][ESS], level: -88, frequency: 2462, timestamp: 238653673422, hs2Info: <none>, distance: ?(cm), distanceSd: ?(cm), SSID: Tech_D0018138, BSSID: 50:09:59:83:ee:05, capabilities: [WPA-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][ESS], level: -91, frequency: 2437, timestamp: 238653673427, hs2Info: <none>, distance: ?(cm), distanceSd: ?(cm)]";
     int idx = s.indexOf("cbtap"); // cbtap998852211C:CF:7F:0A:AC:33,
     if (idx != -1)
     {
        int idx2 = s.indexOf(',',idx);
        s = s.substring(idx,idx2);
        String cbtap = s.substring(0,5);
        idx = s.indexOf(':');
        String id = s.substring(5,idx-2);
        String ip = s.substring(idx-2);
        System.out.println(cbtap+" / "+id+" / "+ip);
     }
```

Comment: yes cbtap is the key and ip is 6 parts only the first part is concatenated with  the 8 digit dynamic number.Also Im working with a **String Array**, so please suggest relevant with the following code:-

Comment: `private class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { String[] wifis; 
        String key = "cbtap"; // cbtap998852211C:CF:7F:0A:AC:33,
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifi.getScanResults();
            wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
            Toast.makeText(WifiManagement.this, "calculated wifi length " +wifis.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
for (int i = 0; i < wifis.length; i++) {
                wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
               }}`

Comment: Thank you .That was really helpful